# Why $-g^{ij}(\nabla_jR_{kl}+\nabla_kR_{jl}-\nabla_lR_{jk})=\nabla Rm$

Tags: riemannian-geometry

Why $-g^{ij}(\nabla_jR_{kl}+\nabla_kR_{jl}-\nabla_lR_{jk})=\nabla Rm$?

Whether the $\nabla Rm(X,Y,Z,W,T)=\nabla_XRm(Y,Z,W,T)$?

Comment: The equation just don't look right. The left hand side has only three indices and the right hand side has five.

Comment: I will check it in the afternoon.